How to plot x,y,z data in a polar stereographic map in matlab?
I have data from the SAR satellite instrument that is already in a polar stereographic projection. The data comes with x,y coordinates, not lat,lon. Can anyone provide insight on how to plot the z data (Normalized Radar Cross Section) on a northern hemisphere azimuthal map? Both the x and y variables range in value from [-5498550, 5498450]
Using imagesc, I am able to confirm the data is at the correct projection because I can see the outline of Greenland. However, I'm not sure how to create the proper map axes in matlab or how to project the z data properly.

Do you have the mapping toolbox? If yes, try this:
xLimits = [-5498550, 5498450];
yLimits = xLimits

% grid
[xGrid, yGrid] = meshgrid(linspace(xLimits(1), xLimits(2), size(z, 2)), ...
                          linspace(yLimits(1), yLimits(2), size(z, 1)));

% Set up the map axes with an azimuthal projection centered on the North Pole
figure;
axesm('MapProjection', 'stereo', 'Origin', [90 0], 'FLatLimit', [60 90]);
axis off
setm(gca, 'MapLatLimit', [-90 90], 'MapLonLimit', [-180 180]);

% Display the data on the map
geoshow(xGrid, yGrid, z, 'DisplayType', 'surface');

mlabel on;
plabel on;
gridm on; 




I do have the mapping toolbox, but unfortunately this code resulted in a large polygon. I was able to get something that looks correct using the following:

proj = projcrs(6931,"Authority",'EPSG');

[plat,plon] = projinv(proj,xvarm,yvarm);


figure('Color','w')
axesm('eqaazim','MapLatLimit',[0 90])
axis off; framem on; gridm on
mlabel on; plabel on;
setm(gca,'MLabelParallel',0)
surfm(plat,plon+45,NRCS)

